# How can I dynamically change the delay within my CCSequence?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have a sequence that I am trying to repeat, and change the delay time with each occurance of the repeat...  Something like:

```
__block CCDelayTime *delayTime = [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:myDelay];

[CCRepeat actionWithAction:[CCSequence actions:
                            [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(doSomething)],
                            delayTime,
                            [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{
                            delayTime.duration = delayTime.duration / 2
                        }....
```

I am getting no where real fast..  Depsite the fact that the instance of CCDelayTime's duration_ ivar is in fact properly getting set to half of its previous value, when stepping through the code, it appears that as soon as control reaches one of the base class' (CCActionInterval) methods such as step or update:, the duration_ ivar is back to the original value (what myDelay was set to).

I spent quite a bit of time going through the cocos code trying to figure out why this is happening but eventually decided to give up and see if anyone here can help me.  Perhaps there is a better way to do what I am trying to do in the first place?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? This seems like it might be a job for scheduled selectors, not actions.

Answer (score 0):

what you do here is: call a function, wait for some time (delay), run a block that changes the waiting time of the action that already ran.

What you need to use is CCSpeed, add the delay action to it, and keep a reference to CCSpeed so that you can modify the speed from *outside* the sequence.

Comment: I tried this, but it's not working--- Perhaps I am misunderstanding you...  I did:  __block CCSpeed *s = [CCSpeed actionWithAction:[CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:0.25f] speed:1];   and I get "[CCSpeed duration]: unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Comment: That's because CCSpeed has no 'duration', use the 'speed' property instead. Though I'm not sure you can change the speed in the block, since the block is called AFTER the delayTime action has stopped running. I'm guessing maybe you should simply recreate the sequence, every time with a new delay. If that's your goal: change the delay for every sequence run rather than changing it *while* the sequence is running. In that case recreating the sequence is the easiest way.